# How to integrate $\exp\left(-ax^2\right)\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate
$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx + c) \, dx$$

to get a closed-form solution?

This integration comes from the second integration when I calculate the possibility $P(|A|<|B|),$ where $A \sim N(\mu _A, \sigma _A^2)$ and $B \sim N(\mu _B, \sigma _B^2)$. I have already obtained the exact numerical result, but now I need a closed-form solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do $\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^2)\operatorname{erf}(x + 1)\;dx$ ... if not, there is no hope for the general one.

Comment: Please add your thoughts on the problem..

Comment: I have already found the equation $[\int\limits_{{\rm{ - }}\infty }^\infty  {{e^{ - p{x^2}}}erf(a + bx)} dx = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{p}} erf(\frac{{a\sqrt p }}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + p} }})$ in 'Table of Integrals, Series, and Products', but I still can not apply it to my integration.

Comment: Use the main definition for the error function, as an integral. You will get a double integral. Then change the order of integration. See what you get. Most likely a similar looking integral, but who knows

Comment: @GEdgar, just for fun, that special case you mention evaluates to $$ 
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \text{erf}(x+1) \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left( 1- \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}^2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am skeptical about a possible closed form.

In the case where $c=0$, there is an explicit result (assuming $a>0$ and $b>0$)
$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx ) \, dx=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi a} }$$ Assuming that $c$ is small, $\operatorname{erf}(bx +c)$ could be expanded as series
$$\operatorname{erf}(bx +c)=\operatorname{erf}(bx)+\frac{2 e^{-b^2 x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\left(c-b  xc^2+\frac{1}{3}  \left(2 b^2 x^2-1\right)c^3-\frac{1}{6}  b x
   \left(2 b^2 x^2-3\right)c^4+O\left(c^5\right) \right)$$

This would lead to
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi a}}+k-\frac{b
   }{\sqrt{\pi }}k^2-\frac{a }{3}k^3+\frac{ b\left(3 a+b^2\right)}{6 \sqrt{\pi
   }}k^4+O\left(c^5\right) \quad\text{with} \quad k=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a+b^2}}$$ The key problem is to find the general term of the expansion of $\operatorname{erf}(bx +c)$ around $c=0$

In any manner, doing it, we should face integrals
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty x^n \,e^{ -\left(a+b^2\right)x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)
   \left(a+b^2\right)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}$$

**Edit**

We can make things a bit simpler.

Let $bx=y$ and $\alpha=\frac a {b^2}$ to make
$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx+c ) \, dx=\frac 1b\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\alpha y^2} \operatorname{erf}(y+c ) \, dy$$

$$\operatorname{erf}(y+c )=\operatorname{erf}(y)+\frac{2 e^{-y^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}c\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor }}{(n+1)!}\,P_{n}(y)\, c^n$$

The polynomials are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(y) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -y \\
 2 & 2 y^2-1 \\
 3 & 3 y-2 y^3 \\
 4 & 4 y^4-12 y^2+3 \\
 5 & -4 y^5+20 y^3-15 y \\
 6 & 8 y^6-60 y^4+90 y^2-15 \\
 7 & -8 y^7+84 y^5-210 y^3+105 y \\
 8 & 16 y^8-224 y^6+840 y^4-840 y^2+105 \\
 9 & -16 y^9+288 y^7-1512 y^5+2520 y^3-945 y \\
10 & 32 y^{10}-720 y^8+5040 y^6-12600 y^4+9450 y^2-945 \\11 & -32 y^{11}+880 y^9-7920 y^7+27720 y^5-34650 y^3+10395 y \\
 12 & 64 y^{12}-2112 y^{10}+23760 y^8-110880 y^6+207900 y^4-124740 y^2+10395
\end{array}
\right)$$ and
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty y^n \,e^{(\alpha +1) \left(-y^2\right)}\,dy=\frac{1}{2} (\alpha +1)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$

It "just" remains to identify these polynomials.

After integration, this would lead tp
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha }}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\alpha }}+k-\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{\alpha  k^3}{3}+\frac{(1247400 \alpha +415800)
   k^4}{2494800 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{\alpha ^2 k^5}{10}-$$ $$\frac{\left(415800 \alpha
   ^2+277200 \alpha +83160\right) k^6}{2494800 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{\alpha ^3
   k^7}{42}+$$ $$\frac{\left(103950 \alpha ^3+103950 \alpha ^2+62370 \alpha
   +14850\right) k^8}{2494800 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{\alpha ^4
   k^9}{216}-$$ $$\frac{\left(20790 \alpha ^4+27720 \alpha ^3+24948 \alpha ^2+11880
   \alpha +2310\right) k^{10}}{2494800 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{\alpha ^5
   k^{11}}{1320}+$$ $$\frac{\left(3465 \alpha ^5+5775 \alpha ^4+6930 \alpha ^3+4950
   \alpha ^2+1925 \alpha +315\right) k^{12}}{2494800 \sqrt{\pi
   }}+O\left(k^{13}\right)$$ where $k=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\alpha +1}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Maybe I should not be obssessed with a closed-form since the real formula is more complicated than what I showed in this question. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @yyyyyaki *"o you who enter here give up all hope"* as Dante wrote in *"The Divine Comedy"* ! Stop dreaming ! Awake ! Back to serious, there is no hope for any closed form.

Comment: Is this polynomial true only when $c$ is around $0$?

Comment: @yyyyyaki. Yes (it is based on the Taylor expansion of the error function around $c=0$). I should be quite cautious with it. It works fine with small $c$'s but it depends very much on the other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Following the derivation given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4317177/695196), we see that for $a >0$ and $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ you *can* obtain the closed form:

> $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx + c) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left(\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b^2}}c\right) + 2 T\left(\sqrt{\frac{2a}{a+b^2}}c, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a}} \right)\right)
> $$

where $T(x,a)$ is [Owen's T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function).